# jQuery Ajax get function from Controller/Model

Tags: jquery, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to "get" the results from a function in my model, "function drop_1($var)"
I've looked at the syntax:
$.get(URL,data,function(data,status,xhr),dataType)
not sure what my url would be or if there is a better way to "get" from Model?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wait_1').hide();
    $('#drop_1').change(function(){
      $('#wait_1').show();
      $('#result_1').hide();
      $.get("url", { 
        func: "drop_1",
        drop_var: $('#drop_1').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_1').fadeOut();
        setTimeout("finishAjax('result_1', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are using a relative path for your URI.  Have you checked that this relative path works?

Comment: tried that and the full url but if I put my full url into a browser, it doesn't show. I don't think controllers are meant to be accessed that way.

Comment: if I put the "function drop_1($drop_var)" in my model, then maybe I can get rid of the $.get altogether but I still need to get the results from that function.

Comment: you don't get from model, you get from the controller

Comment: you need to create a method in the controller to run the function and return the result in your format (json, html, whatever). The url to this controller action/method becomes the url you use for ajax.